# How to find the angle in between two triangles?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is indicated in the figure from below:

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&10^{\circ}\\
2.&15^{\circ}\\
3.&20^{\circ}\\
4.&18^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

What exactly should be done here?. I'm stuck. The only thing which I can spot is that:

$\angle DAC + x = 55$

$\angle BAC + 40 = \angle BCD + 55$

But without any other further knowledge, I don't know what else can be done here?. Can someone help me here?. **Can this problem be solved relying only in euclidean geometry?**.

The other thing which I can spot is since it says $BD \parallel AC$

This means:

$\angle BDA = \angle DAC$

But again this information doesn't really help me much into solving this problem. Can someone guide me further?. **Please include a drawing in the answer because I'm lost**. Does this requires a construction?.

Comment: Hint: You can draw a circle centered at B, passing through A, C, D, and then use the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle)

Answer (score 8):

If $AB=BC=BD$, then $B$ is the centre of circle with $A,C,D$ on the circumference and the angle $\angle ADC$ is [half the angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) $\angle ABC$, i.e. $20^\circ$

Comment: Note that this solution works even without assuming BD // AC.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yep, I didn't need that at all - I saw it but I didn't even consider it after seeing $B$ as the circle origin.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

At first (blue angles), notice how the $ABC$ triangle is isosceles (since $AB=BC$), and you get that the bottom angles are both $70$ (because $\frac{180-40}{2}=70$). Then, since $BD\| AC$, you can find that the angle next to the $40$º is also $70$, and that the big angle that contains the $x$ is $55$.

Finally (red angles), we also know $AB=BD$, so the triangle $ABD$ is also isosceles and we know one angle is $40+70=110$, so the other two must be $35$ (because $\frac{180-110}{2}=35$).

So your $x$ is
$$\boxed{x=55-35=20}$$

Ask me is there's anything you don't understand, maybe I explained it too fast.

Comment: You explained it perfectly well.